# How could I give a inherited class function to a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, inheritance, target

```
import threading
class A:
    def func(self):
        print('asdf')

class B(A):
    def func(self):
        print('1234')

class C(A):
    def func(self):
        print('xyzw')
def f(inner_func):
    class_list = [A(),B(),C()]
    thread_list = []
    for i in class_list:
        x=threading.Thread(target=inner_func(i,),args=())
        thread_list.append(x)
        x.start()
    for i in thread_list:
        i.join()
f(A.func)
```

I thought this would print

```
asdf
1234
xyzw
```

but it just prints

```
asdf
asdf
asdf
```

How can I use the inherited classes' functions at once, without doing it manually?
I want to give the inner_func with an argument, so I could use it with different functions. 
For example, if class A,B,C had another function `func2`, I could use it as `f(A.func2)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, each thread is executing `A.func` with `self` set to an instance of `A`, `B` and `C`. In no case does it access `B.func` or `C.func`. There is no possible object in Python that refers to `A.func` or `B.func` or `C.func` depending on the context.

What you need to do instead is pass the *name* of the function you wish to execute, then retrieve the appropriate function from the desired instance or class. So, the last call needs to be `f("func")`; the function `f` needs to be changed appropriately. Specifically, you can use `getattr(A, 'func')` to get the unbound method (which you could then invoke as `method(A())`), or you can use `getattr(A(), 'func')` to get a bound method (which you could invoke as `method()`).

(Also, off-topic, but using `i` for both threads and instances is super confusing, as is naming a list of instances `class_list`.)

```
def f(method_name):
    instance_list = [A(), B(), C()]
    thread_list = []
    for instance in instance_list:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=getattr(instance, method_name), args=())
        thread_list.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

f('func')
```